# How can I allow a user to input the parameters he/she wants within a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I made a basic calculator class with addition subtraction multiplication and division in it as functions. How can I allow the user to input what `(x, y)` he/she wants while using the calculator?

```
class Calc:
    def addition(x, y):
        print(f'your result is{x} + {y}')

    def subtraction(x, y):
        print(f'your result is{x} - {y}')

    def multiplication(x, y):
        print(f'your result is{x} * {y}')

    def division(x, y):
        print(f'your result is{x} / {y}')

    def rounded_division(x, y):
        print(f'your result is{x} // {y}')
```

something like: 'what operation do you want to perform?: (user input)'
then 'what numbers do you want to perform this operation with?'

Comment: What's the problem? Just use `num1 = int(input("First number"))` and `num2 = int(input("Second number"))`, then call the appropriate function.

Comment: Note: you're not actually calculating the results within your strings

Answer (score 1):

You can take the inputs for `x` and `y` in the `__init__()` method of the class. The init method will request the inputs when the class is instantiated.

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = int(input("What is x?"))
        self.y = int(input("What is y?"))

    def addition(self):
        print('your result is {}'.format((self.x+self.y)))

    def subtraction(self):
        print('your result is {}'.format((self.x-self.y)))

    def multiplication(self):
        print('your result is {}'.format((self.x*self.y)))

    def division(self):
        print('your result is {}'.format((self.x/self.y)))

    def rounded_division(self):
        print('your result is {}'.format((self.x//self.y)))
```

Output and calculation calls would look like this:

```
>>> calc = Calc()
What is x?>? 4
What is y?>? 3
>>> calc.addition()
your result is 7
>>> calc.subtraction()
your result is 1
>>> calc.multiplication()
your result is 12
>>> calc.division()
your result is 1.3333333333333333
>>> calc.rounded_division()
your result is 1
```